# How respected. valued is the CFA when applying for finance jobs?

Tags: qualification

Is this a qualification that companies genuinely seek out?

Comment: This falls into what skills to learn,  so off topic. Voting to close.

Comment: I disagree, you can learn these skills many ways.  The question is about how people specifically regard the qualification itself in terms of respecting that it conveys knowledge of said skills and whether a premium /valuation is place on it -  per DVK's answer.

Comment: The whole thing of asking if a CFA is wothwhile is about one specific qualification and how it may relate to your job search.  As such this is a poor fit to the site, we look for questions that can be helpful to a wide audience,  and especially given the brevity of what you ask I've voted to close it.

Comment: I'm missing a country tag and an explanation of the abrreviation. This is an international site.

Comment: Sorry Jan.  This is not country specific, the CFA is an international qualification.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartered_Financial_Analyst

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to the "finance jobs" in general, but I know of at least two large companies in asset management industry which value CFA to the point of:

- Fully cover the CFA study costs (assuming you pass), whereas they barely if at all cover any other continuing education.
- Have explicit policies allowing taking paid time off for CFA prep and exams.

Money talks, so the above two policies show clear value assigned by the company to CFA for existing hire, which obviously commensurately raises the value of a new hire.

---

"300 hours" has [an article on CFA salaries](http://www.300hours.com/articles/7-reasons-to-consider-the-cfa-charter#.V1xMqigrKUk), with the following relevant conlusion:

> However there are some recent studies on comparing the effects of compensation of roles with and without the CFA charter - that is to say, studies that attempt to place a ‘monetary value’ on the CFA charter.
>
> The CFA Institute last covered this in their 2005 compensation survey, **where the concluded that CFA charterholders’ median salary was 54% higher than non CFA charterholders (a median annual salary of $180,000 for charterholders vs $116,850 for non charterholders)**. This was a higher effect that even MBAs. But note that this was back in 2005, so make your own conclusions.

Having said that, "300 hours" has [another article, analyzing in detail why figuring out attribution of CFA on salary is not a simple task](http://www.300hours.com/articles/why-its-useless-to-search-for-cfa-salary-data-and-how-we-can-help#.V1xOJigrKUk).

---

Business Insider had a (IMHO, slightly fluffy) [article on CFA vs. MBA](http://www.businessinsider.com/mba-vs-cfa-2013-4). The article itself is not of much value, but it has an interesting salary chart:

[image]

One thing that the article emphasizes and is to an extent true is that CFA is a far more of a niche achievement than MBA. CFA would be extremely valued in buy-side (asset management) financial companies, somewhat valued at sell-side financial companies, but probably a bit less so outside those 2 industries.

Comment: Nice chart, it's pretty interesting to see that the CFA which is much much cheaper than an MBA seems to be associated with higher salaries

Comment: I wonder how these numbers were gathered? From what I know and have witnessed, a lot of companies pay their CFO's and higher end executives via a profit sharing scheme (i.e. the end of year of profits determines the large part of their salary). So, it is interesting to account that in as well as keeping in mind pay changes based on position/responsibilities with little regard for education. Bottom line, almost any kind of accounting/finance certification will be a tremendous help in those industries. MBA's are better for management and for more general fields.

Comment: Most people who do the CFA do it on their employer's coin. Therefore the set of CFA holders is largely drawn from people able to land a front office job in finance. That's why the salary is so high and if you lack similar skills/qualifications then self-funding the CFA won't help you much.